# How to use different methods on the same accordion menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am making an accordion menu for a page that has three images. The first image, 5k/10k, should show/hide the ul underneath the image when clicked. The second image, half-marathon, should slideup/down the ul when clicked. And the third image, full-marathon, should fadein/out the ul when clicked. No two ul's should show at the same time. I am having trouble with this, can you please help? Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>FV Runners</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
    </div> <!-- End of 'header' div-->

    <div id="main">
    </div>  <!-- End of 'main' div-->

    <div id="pics">

        <div class="race_box">
            <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
            <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

            <div class="races" id="5k">
                <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Mini Sprint</br>10/30/17</br>Memorial Park</br>
                        Appleton</li>
                    <li>Iron Horse</br>11/06/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                    <li>Twilight Trail</br>11/13/17</br>River's Edge Park</br>Wrightstown</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
        </div> <!-- End of 'run1' div-->

        <div class="race_box">
            <img src="images/run2.jpg" /><br />
            <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>

            <div class="races" id="half">
                <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/17</br>Pierce Park</br>Appleton</li>
                    <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                    <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/17</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- End of 'half' div-->
        </div><!-- End of 'run2' div-->

        <div class="race_box">
            <img src="images/run3.jpg" /><br />
            <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

        <div class="races" id="full">
            <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/17</br>Pamperin Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/17</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End of 'full' div-->
        </div> <!-- End of 'run3' div-->

    </div> <!-- End of 'pics' div-->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript so far. I know it's not a lot, but I've been trying different things and just started from scratch:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var accordian = $('.race_box');

    accordian.find('.races').hide();

    $('.race_box').click(function(){
        $('#5k').toggle(); 
    });
});
```

Updated attempt at Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var accordian = $('.race_box');

    accordian.find('.races').hide();

   accordian.find('.race_box').on('click', function(){
   $(this).next('.races').slideToggle(); 
   });

   /*$('.race_box').click(function(){
   $('#5k').slideToggle(); 
   });*/
});
```

Update: Still have not been able to figure this out. Still working at it

Does anyone have any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to use a different show/hide method on each `ul`, I think the easiest thing to do is just have three different click functions. The code isn't quite as elegant, but it's easily readable.

Basic approach is:

1. On image click,
2. Use the appropriate method – either `.toggle()`, `.slideToggle()`, or `.fadeToggle()` – to show the matching list, then
3. Check if any other lists are visible, and if so, hide them using their appropriate method.

I would hide all the lists with CSS initially, instead of using JavaScript. That way, you won't have to worry about the lists potentially showing up for a split second as the page loads, before the JavaScript runs.

Final note, unrelated to the JS: for your line break tags, either simply do `<br>` or, if you want to include a slash, make it `<br/>`. `</br>` is invalid HTML.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var fiveK = document.getElementById('5k'),
      half = document.getElementById('half'),
      full = document.getElementById('full');

  var fiveKImg = $(fiveK).prev().prev().prev(),
      halfImg = $(half).prev().prev().prev(),
      fullImg = $(full).prev().prev().prev();

  $(fiveKImg).on('click', function() {
    $(fiveK).toggle();

    if ($(half).is(':visible')) {
      $(half).slideToggle();
    }
    if ($(full).is(':visible')) {
      $(full).fadeToggle();
    }
  });

  $(halfImg).on('click', function() {
    $(half).slideToggle();

    if ($(fiveK).is(':visible')) {
      $(fiveK).toggle();
    }
    if ($(full).is(':visible')) {
      $(full).fadeToggle();
    }
  });

  $(fullImg).on('click', function() {
    $(full).fadeToggle();

    if ($(fiveK).is(':visible')) {
      $(fiveK).toggle();
    }
    if ($(half).is(':visible')) {
      $(half).slideToggle();
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.races {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pics">

  <div class="race_box">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300?text=run%201" /><br />
    <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

    <div class="races" id="5k">
      <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Mini Sprint<br>10/30/17<br>Memorial Park<br> Appleton
        </li>
        <li>Iron Horse<br>11/06/17<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
        <li>Twilight Trail<br>11/13/17<br>River's Edge Park<br>Wrightstown</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!--  End of '5k' div-->
  </div>
  <!-- End of 'run1' div-->

  <div class="race_box">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300?text=run%202" /><br />
    <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>

    <div class="races" id="half">
      <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/17<br>Pierce Park<br>Appleton</li>
        <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/17<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
        <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/17<br>Menominee Park<br>Oshkosh</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End of 'half' div-->
  </div>
  <!-- End of 'run2' div-->

  <div class="race_box">
    <img src="https://placehold.it/300x300?text=run%203" /><br />
    <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

    <div class="races" id="full">
      <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
      <ul>
        <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/17<br>Pamperin Park<br>Green Bay</li>
        <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/17<br>Bay Beach Park<br>Green Bay</li>
        <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/17<br>Menominee Park<br>Oshkosh</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End of 'full' div-->
  </div>
  <!-- End of 'run3' div-->

</div>
<!-- End of 'pics' div-->
```

Comment: Awesome thank you so much! You were right about hiding it in the css, that works out much better. Also, I had to change the .on('click', function() to just .click( function() because that worked but on click did not. Either way, thank you!

Comment: @nponinski No problem! `.on('click', function(){...` vs `.click(function()...` is probably due to different versions of jQuery, FYI. If the latter works for you, great :)

Answer (score 0):

Onclick of a race_box, hide all the races class , then find the next race and show it.  Hope this helps...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>FV Runners</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link href="styles/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="styles/my_style.css" rel="stylesheet" />


</head>
<body>
    <div id="header">
        <h1>Fox Valley Runners Club</h1>
    </div> <!-- End of 'header' div-->

    <div id="main">
    </div>  <!-- End of 'main' div-->

    <div id="pics">

        <div class="race_box" data-toggle="slideToggle">
            <img src="images/run1.jpg" /><br />
            <figcaption>5k/10k Events</figcaption>

            <div class="races" id="5k">
                <h3>5k/10 Events</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Mini Sprint</br>10/30/17</br>Memorial Park</br>
                        Appleton</li>
                    <li>Iron Horse</br>11/06/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                    <li>Twilight Trail</br>11/13/17</br>River's Edge Park</br>Wrightstown</li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--  End of '5k' div-->
        </div> <!-- End of 'run1' div-->

        <div class="race_box" data-toggle="toggle">
            <img src="images/run2.jpg" /><br />
            <figcaption>Half Marathon Events</figcaption>
            <div class="races" id="half">
                <h3>Half Marathon Events</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li>Fox River Marathon 10/15/17</br>Pierce Park</br>Appleton</li>
                    <li>N.E.W. Half Marathon 10/29/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                    <li>Winnebago Run 11/27/17</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
                </ul>
            </div> <!-- End of 'half' div-->
        </div><!-- End of 'run2' div-->

        <div class="race_box" data-toggle="fadeToggle">
            <img src="images/run3.jpg" /><br />
            <figcaption>Full Marathon Events</figcaption>

        <div class="races" id="full">
            <h3>Full Marathon Events</h3>
            <ul>
                <li>Cheesehead Marathon 9/24/17</br>Pamperin Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                <li>Chain O'Lakes Marathon 10/29/17</br>Bay Beach Park</br>Green Bay</li>
                <li>Fox Cities Marathon 11/12/17</br>Menominee Park</br>Oshkosh</li>
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- End of 'full' div-->
        </div> <!-- End of 'run3' div-->

    </div> <!-- End of 'pics' div-->
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>


<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        //var accordian = $('.race_box');
        $('.races').hide();

        $('.race_box').click(function(){
            console.log($(this));
           //$('.races').hide();
            //console.log($(this).find('.races')) ;
            var method = $(this).attr("data-toggle");
            console.log(method);
            var nextRace = $(this).find('.races');
            //nextRace.show(); 
            switch(method) {
                case "slideToggle" :
                    nextRace.slideToggle(1000);
                break;
                case "toggle" :
                    nextRace.toggle(1000);
                break;
                case "fadeToggle" :
                    nextRace.fadeToggle(1000);
                break;            

            }


        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes that does help a little bit. However, I cannot just show all the ul's for the race-boxes. One has to be show, one slideup/down, and one fadein/out. How do I set those specific methods to the specified images on click? I can do all as show, but not sure if accordion allows you to do different methods for different images...

Comment: Edited to incorporate different methods. Do check.